# Minify, how to clear cache?

Tags: php, zend-framework, minify

I'm using Zend Framework with [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/),

I updated Jquery and JqueryUI javascripts,

I cleared all browser cache, restarted the webserver,

but I still get the old files, **how can I make it see the new files** ?

I checked the file create/modify date, it's today(since I unziped them), I'm on Windows, don't know if that changes anything

I'm using Firebug and I see the old jquery 1.5.1 instead of the new 1.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the same setup, and in minify config, you can setup a base directory for your cache files. If you don't specify it, it defaults to - as I remember - the webservers' tmp folder. If you do not see your changes, it usually means, these files are still on the system, so a simple Ctrl+F5 won't clear out the server side cache files.

```
Minify config example:
$min_cachePath = '/var/www/example.com/cache/minify';
```

**Update for you:**

**Example using WAMP server on windows:**

example.com is at: d:/www/example.com

minify folder: d:/www/example.com/htdocs/static/utils/min *(note: you can also have min under example.com/htdocs/min, it is just how I prefer it)*

in min/config.php I have this:

```
$min_allowDebugFlag = false;
$min_errorLogger = false;
$min_enableBuilder = false;

$min_cachePath = 'd:/www/example.com/cache/minify';

$min_documentRoot = '';
$min_cacheFileLocking = true;
$min_serveOptions['bubbleCssImports'] = false;
$min_serveOptions['maxAge'] = 31556926;
$min_serveOptions['minApp']['groupsOnly'] = false;
$min_serveOptions['minApp']['maxFiles'] = 10;
```

**So basically I set it relative to the site root, not to the server's own tmp directory.**

Comment: hey thanks, i didn't have variable set up, i set it to "c:\www\tmp" but no files appear in that folder, i'm using EasyPhp, where can i this temporary folder?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but if it is not working for you, try the documentation here: http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/AlternateFileLayouts

Comment: the solution was to edit the file and then minify saw it, must be something wrong with windows... the documentation says:         Cache files won't update

If you upload files using Coda or Transmit or from a Windows PC to a non-Windows server, your new files may end up with the wrong timestamp on the server, confusing the cache system.

Setting the $min_uploaderHoursBehind option in config.php can compensate for this

Comment: hey! well, on windows, everything is just a tad bit different... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that all the minified files are recreated with your updated JavaScript or CSS, remove all the minified files from the temporary folder(s).

On a Linux system, do this:

```
sudo rm /tmp/minify_*
```

On a Windows system, do this:

```
DEL %TEMP%\minify_* %SystemRoot%\Temp\minify_*
```